# Autocompletar un Input basándose en un select con datos de la base de datos

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

tengo un select y contiene los datos de mi base de datos mi duda es la siguiente como puedo llenar los input segun la seleccion de mi select

```
 <select id="buscador" name="buscador" class="form-control insertarbtn" style="width: 100%">

           <?php foreach($prt_resultado_c as $row)
            {
          ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $row['nombre']."  ".$row['presentacion']; ?>
        </option>
        <?php
        }
```

?>

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Cantidad</label>  
        <input type="text" name="cantidad" class="form-control" value="" />
        </div>
```

Comment: Prueba usando el evento [change de los input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event), así cuando haya un cambio en tu select, llenas tus inputs

Comment: lei "change de los input" y no lo entendi lo que me quiso decir podrias explicame lo mejor disculpe (.>..<.) @gaidyjg gaidyjg

Comment: Esto es la varian $prt_resultado_c   
**<?php 
$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','inventarioivss');
$prt_consulta = "SELECT * FROM lista";
$prt_resultado_c =mysqli_query($conexion,$prt_consulta);
?>**

Comment: Voto de cierre: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado. A parte de informarte de que tu aplicación es vulnerable a ataques [**XSS (cross-site scripting)**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), ¿nos podrías poner un ejemplo de en qué afecta la selección de `<select>` al contenido del `<input>`?

Comment: no afecta en nada el select, solo quiero que mi input traiga el contenido del datos que selecione en el select es todo

Answer (score 2):

**Primero**, date una vuelta por el [Tour de StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) así aprendes como funciona.

**Segundo**, [@gaidyjg](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/184555/gaidyjg) te brindo una solución a tu pregunta, si estas encaminando el mundo del desarrollo web, debes aprender a leer e interpretar, testea con prueba y error, así aprenderás, no esperes a que te pasen el código para copiar y pegar, a menos que pagues por el servicio, **este sitio tiene como objetivo ayudarte a resolver tus dudas, no hacer tu trabajo**.

**Tercero**, veo que manejas PHP, para lograr lo que deseas, debes utilizar JavaScript, pero dicha acción recomendable no es, por el motivo que te menciono [@OscarGarcia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18608/oscargarcia), en el enlace que te proporciono tienes ejemplos claros del por que.

De igual manera, te dejo el codigo JS implementado en el ejemplo que diste en la pregunta, y bienvenida a la comunidad :3

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector(".insertarbtn");

selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const result = document.querySelector("input[name='cantidad']");
  result.value = `${event.target.value}`;
});
```

```html
<select id="buscador" name="buscador" class="form-control insertarbtn" style="width: 100%">
<option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
<option value="2">Opcion 2</option>
<option value="3">Opcion 3</option>
<option value="4">Opcion 4</option>
<option value="5">Opcion 5</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="">Cantidad</label>  
<input name="cantidad" type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por el codigo pero ese es el mismo que eh estado implementando y nada que me sale por eso pedi el codigo a ver si yo estaba haciendo algo malo